# Playing successive wav sounds in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, external, wav

I am trying to play through AS3 external wav sounds in a successive way. The obvious way to do it is to use this algorithm:
1. play sound 1
2. when sound 1 is done, play sound 2
etc.

The problem is that I fail the step number 2 (the "when sound 1 is done" part).

Please answer for wav sounds only, NOT mp3.

Here is my code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import org.as3wavsound.WavSound;
    import org.as3wavsound.WavSoundChannel;

    public final class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public final function Main():void
        {
            playB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, loadWav);
        }

        private final function loadWav(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('Phone.wav');
            var wav:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            wav.dataFormat = 'binary';
            wav.load(urlRequest);
            wav.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, playWav);
        }

        private final function playWav(e:Event):void
        {
            var tts:WavSound = new WavSound(e.target.data as ByteArray);
            tts.play();
        }
    }
}
```

(This is step 1 of course)

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your sound into a SoundChannel - which is returned from the play command, then listen for the complete event:

```
private final function playWav(e:Event):void
{
    var tts:WavSound = new WavSound(e.target.data as ByteArray);
    var channel:WavSoundChannel = tts.play();
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, completeHandler)
}

private function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    //play next sound
}
```

Comment: Not really working! Get me error : 1136:Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 5.

Comment: The error is in line 32. I am sending the last part of the code:            31 private final function playWav(e:Event):void
32  {
31   var tts:WavSound = new WavSound(e.target.data as ByteArray);
32   var channel:WavSoundChannel = new WavSoundChannel();
33   channel = tts.play();
34  }
35 }
36}     The rest are the same

Comment: Your not using the code as shown in my example.  Your instantiating WavSoundChannel,  but you don't need to do this.  the play() method returns an already instantiated WavSoundChannel